# Fibonacci applied to human population living to dead ratio problem

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

If this forum is not the right one for my question, please redirect it. I do not know where to ask it.
The question might seem tongue-in-cheek, believe me it's not!

Last week to occupy my mind, I used this little mathematics trick to find the ratio of all long gone dead people since the beginning of time to this time around living persons:

I started with a pair of organisms (male-female, m-f) which procreate once in a year to produce 1 pair of m-f offspring which in turn grow to sexual maturity in the next year to produce 1 pair of m-f offspring. Each couple are faithful to one-another and remain together for the rest of their lives which is exactly 3 years, and they don't cheat with other males or females of the species to produce out of marriage offspring.

So in the first year we get: m0-f0 to produce nil: 2(0+1) living organisms in total.
In the second year we get: m0-f0 to produce m01-f01: 2(1+1) living organisms in total.
In the third year: m0-f0 to produce m02-f02, m01-f01 to produce m011-f011: 2(1+1+2) living organisms in total.

In the fourth year mo-f0 dies, so we strike the first term out (the 1 to the left) of our Fibonacci series in parenthesis,
Easy to see now: m01-f01 produces m012-f012, m02-f02 produces m021-f021, m011-f011 produces m0111-f0111: 2(1+2+3) living organisms in total.
In the fifth year: 2(2+3+5), since m01-f01 die.
In the sixth year 2(3+5+8), since m02-f02 and m011-f011 and die.
....................................................................... ...................

What we have here, are the three consecutive terms of a Fibonacci sequence added together, multiplied by the number of offspring (2) each couple begets each year.
After many terms a little math is showing us that:
1. The ratio of the living now to all the dead so far is exactly 2φ, where φ is the Greek Golden ratio number, equal to: 1+ √5. So the living each year outnumber all the dead so far.
2. The population growth each year is exactly φ.

Now, to see this with people, replace each 1 year with 1 generation life-span: approximately 30 years, so each person-couple lives 3*30=90 years and then dies.
In the example above, each couple waits to sexual maturity 1 year (30 yrs with people) and then for the remaining 2 years of their life, they procreate 2*2=4 offspring, in total. Same with people, in the remaining 60 years of their lives, they beget 4 offspring. But 4 offspring is too many for a couple of humans, so let's just say they are having just 1 offspring every 30 years. So, we are 
replacing the number 2 before each of our parenthesis with 1 to get a Fibonacci sequence sum:
2+3+5, 3+5+8, 5+8+13....... for every thirty years, with humans.

Ergo:

1. The ratio of the living persons now to all the dead people so far is exactly 2φ, where φ is the Greek Golden ratio number, equal to: 1+ √5. So the living each year outnumber all the dead so far.
2. The population growth every 30 years is exactly φ≈1.61.

After this, I returned happy home and googled the internet only to find that the dead people so far exceed 100 billion, and other assorted kind of nonsense (please forgive my language).
Is this insane or what?
When even without maths this premise is fallacious.

Because:
1. Starting with Adam and Eve (some preposterous claim), when Adam and Eve they die, certainly their offspring outnumber them, if their number is bigger than two.
2. If all the dead so far are 100 billion and the living today 7.25 billion, then by decree tomorrow, by severe penalty of law, each female of the human species could be forced to give birth to a child each year and for the rest of their lives, so that the living after a few years could easily outnumber all the dead.

Thank you for your precious time, please answer me if I am any if at all wrong.

Comment: Question is too long, and too incest....